# Visual Studio IDE Feature: Filters; What is the Filter property used for?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When you are in a solution and have the "Show All Files" button disabled in the Solution Explorer.  You see a logical (filtered) view with some sort of "virtual" folders called filters.

You can add new filters (Right Click Project -> Add -> New Filter).  You can add new files under a filter, or drag and drop existing files into an existing filter (they behave much as if they were actual folders).

On the properties page of a filter there's a few properties.  Some are self-explanatory:

- Parse Files: True/False: Files in this filter are parsed for
  autocomplete and other designers
- SCC Files: True/False: Files in this filter are available to version control systems.

What I can't understand is the:

- Filter: Text input: Specifies a filter.

For example, a default C++ app might have a Source Files filter with a Filter property of: `cpp;c;cc;cxx;def;odl;idl;hpj;bat;asm;asmx`.  However, it doesn't really matter what I change here, I could blank it out, or replace it with something like `txt` I don't see any differences.  I'm not sure how this is even used by Visual Studio, and I could not find any references on its use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter property is used when you add an item to the Project (not to the filter itself). The filter property is used to determine to which filter the new item will be added.

Comment: Visual Studio brings hitherto undiscovered dimensions of uselessness to the table.